# KSQL server not able to run normally after restart with large number of streams registered

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb, confluent-platform

I am running KSQL server in the interactive mode to be able to create streams on the fly (as per business need), when I reached around 400 stream running at the same time, the KSQL server when it was starting at the first time and got the 400 streams created, it was ok and processing them normally, after the first restart (e.g. a new deployment), it got stuck with printing the below lines of logs forever and never get into stable running state.

KSQL is running on K8S, I am using version 5.3.3, with 3 CPU and 16GB memory and heap size 15GB, and each stream is with a single thread and processing a dedicated topic with 2 partitions.

Any Idea what could be happening during the deployment restart that lead to the kind of stuck, knowing that in the first run after creating the 400 stream, the memory and CPU were not congested.

Also below the grafana dashboard for CPU and memory when it get in that weird state (cpu and memory seems to be relaxed).

[image]

```
[2020-05-07 09:25:05,183] INFO stream-thread [_confluent-ksql-service-defaultquery_CSAS_FILTERED_DOCUMENTS_4E78D0B1_447F_4C21_90F1_42FC48E78F86_SELECT_539-1b778679-e576-4e86-8d48-06035c650f3e-StreamThread-1-consumer] Assigned tasks to clients as {d90d9fda-6d29-4504-b8fc-4de19acdf6fa=[activeTasks: ([0_0]) standbyTasks: ([]) assignedTasks: ([0_0]) prevActiveTasks: ([]) prevStandbyTasks: ([]) prevAssignedTasks: ([]) capacity: 1], 1b778679-e576-4e86-8d48-06035c650f3e=[activeTasks: ([0_1]) standbyTasks: ([]) assignedTasks: ([0_1]) prevActiveTasks: ([]) prevStandbyTasks: ([]) prevAssignedTasks: ([]) capacity: 1]}. (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor:653)
[2020-05-07 09:25:05,264] INFO stream-thread [_confluent-ksql-service-defaultquery_CSAS_FILTERED_DOCUMENTS_1E43CB82_555B_4962_B8E8_62FC80BECB99_SELECT_725-4af79071-33ac-4fab-b1b1-d36e7b7dca5b-StreamThread-1-consumer] Assigned tasks to clients as {4af79071-33ac-4fab-b1b1-d36e7b7dca5b=[activeTasks: ([0_0]) standbyTasks: ([]) assignedTasks: ([0_0]) prevActiveTasks: ([]) prevStandbyTasks: ([]) prevAssignedTasks: ([]) capacity: 1], 85e070a9-1c38-44b3-89f1-32d189cb3322=[activeTasks: ([0_1]) standbyTasks: ([]) assignedTasks: ([0_1]) prevActiveTasks: ([]) prevStandbyTasks: ([]) prevAssignedTasks: ([]) capacity: 1]}. (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor:653)
[2020-05-07 09:25:05,398] INFO stream-thread [_confluent-ksql-service-defaultquery_CSAS_FILTERED_DOCUMENTS_354534CF_CF63_4FA1_A150_D485EB16BD60_SELECT_828-3c2e0b47-b5d2-48d0-8fea-a0d6838e33a3-StreamThread-1-consumer] Assigned tasks to clients as {fe1c8e60-3641-494b-bb81-5925616b7e3e=[activeTasks: ([0_0]) standbyTasks: ([]) assignedTasks: ([0_0]) prevActiveTasks: ([]) prevStandbyTasks: ([]) prevAssignedTasks: ([]) capacity: 1], 3c2e0b47-b5d2-48d0-8fea-a0d6838e33a3=[activeTasks: ([0_1]) standbyTasks: ([]) assignedTasks: ([0_1]) prevActiveTasks: ([]) prevStandbyTasks: ([]) prevAssignedTasks: ([]) capacity: 1]}. (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor:653)
[2020-05-07 09:25:05,492] INFO stream-thread [_confluent-ksql-service-defaultquery_CSAS_FILTERED_DOCUMENTS_5231FEE3_9075_47D0_B8E2_EB3542F9D9A7_SELECT_800-68e7747b-37ff-4136-80f1-3776d23f2beb-StreamThread-1-consumer] Assigned tasks to clients as {00657bf4-8fe3-410d-a79c-f4cb4be6a99c=[activeTasks: ([0_0]) standbyTasks: ([]) assignedTasks: ([0_0]) prevActiveTasks: ([]) prevStandbyTasks: ([]) prevAssignedTasks: ([]) capacity: 1], 68e7747b-37ff-4136-80f1-3776d23f2beb=[activeTasks: ([0_1]) standbyTasks: ([]) assignedTasks: ([0_1]) prevActiveTasks: ([]) prevStandbyTasks: ([]) prevAssignedTasks: ([]) capacity: 1]}. (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor:653)
[2020-05-07 09:25:05,581] INFO stream-thread [_confluent-ksql-service-defaultquery_CSAS_FILTERED_DOCUMENTS_E89BA86F_3593_4EE5_8008_EA14683C0BD2_SELECT_853-7b7e8260-f03f-4085-9a0b-f6eee01df50e-StreamThread-1-consumer] Assigned tasks to clients as {7b7e8260-f03f-4085-9a0b-f6eee01df50e=[activeTasks: ([0_0]) standbyTasks: ([]) assignedTasks: ([0_0]) prevActiveTasks: ([]) prevStandbyTasks: ([]) prevAssignedTasks: ([]) capacity: 1], 78e6a093-042e-4020-81a4-bf55fa99635a=[activeTasks: ([0_1]) standbyTasks: ([]) assignedTasks: ([0_1]) prevActiveTasks: ([]) prevStandbyTasks: ([]) prevAssignedTasks: ([]) capacity: 1]}. (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor:653)
[2020-05-07 09:25:05,691] INFO stream-thread [_confluent-ksql-service-defaultquery_CSAS_FILTERED_DOCUMENTS_E18CFAB3_BCB7_47AE_AD43_406DCEA3C798_SELECT_825-a2cde456-b114-448b-bbf1-63f6ba4ec3e9-StreamThread-1-consumer] Assigned tasks to clients as {a2cde456-b114-448b-bbf1-63f6ba4ec3e9=[activeTasks: ([0_0]) standbyTasks: ([]) assignedTasks: ([0_0]) prevActiveTasks: ([]) prevStandbyTasks: ([]) prevAssignedTasks: ([]) capacity: 1], b561d421-93d7-4386-9f7c-d6a2bdc31310=[activeTasks: ([0_1]) standbyTasks: ([]) assignedTasks: ([0_1]) prevActiveTasks: ([]) prevStandbyTasks: ([]) prevAssignedTasks: ([]) capacity: 1]}. (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor:653)
[2020-05-07 09:25:05,711] INFO stream-thread [_confluent-ksql-service-defaultquery_CSAS_FILTERED_DOCUMENTS_6224562D_DD04_490B_B4C0_736F8C64C2ED_SELECT_785-03f86096-3018-4596-a81b-af44e9aeb5af-StreamThread-1-consumer] Assigned tasks to clients as {b1be053f-cea7-4ceb-ae69-ae608df26df3=[activeTasks: ([0_0]) standbyTasks: ([]) assignedTasks: ([0_0]) prevActiveTasks: ([]) prevStandbyTasks: ([]) prevAssignedTasks: ([]) capacity: 1], 03f86096-3018-4596-a81b-af44e9aeb5af=[activeTasks: ([0_1]) standbyTasks: ([]) assignedTasks: ([0_1]) prevActiveTasks: ([]) prevStandbyTasks: ([]) prevAssignedTasks: ([]) capacity: 1]}. (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor:653)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Those log lines are related to consumer group rebalancing. If you are seeing them repeatedly its likely your consumer groups are unstable. This is probably due to high load on the server as it starts up and tries to process the backlog of messages that have built up while the server was offline.  Before the restart the nodes where processing at a steady state and under less load.

To resolve you will need to scale your cluster to reduce the load, or maybe adjust the consumer group rebalancing configuration to stabilize the consumer groups.   The consumer config can be set in the server properties files.

The most important ones to look at are:

- [`session.timeout.ms`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#session.timeout.ms)
- [`max.poll.interval.ms`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#max.poll.interval.ms)
- [`max.partition.fetch.bytes`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#max.partition.fetch.bytes)
- [`max.poll.records`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#max.poll.records)